# Update All References to Cached Object in Dictionary

Tags: c#, caching, dictionary, reference

I have a simple cache of objects:

```
Dictionary<int, Person> personCache = ...
personCache.Add(1, new Person(){ID = 1, Name = "John"});
personCache.Add(2, new Person(){ID = 2, Name = "Mary"});

personCache[1].Manager=personCache[2];
```

(In reality, I have proper encapsulation of the dictionary)

So now John's manager is set to Mary. However, if I want to replace Mary with a new instance of person, if I do

```
personCache[2] = new Person(){ID = 2, Name = "Kate"});
```

References to Mary are not replaced with references to Kate - i.e. John's manager is not updated.

I can see why this is - the dictionary has a reference to Kate, but John still holds a reference to Mary.

Can anyone suggest a way such that

```
personCache[2] = new Person(){ID = 2, Name = "Kate"});
```

Would have the 'expected' result and replace all references to Mary with a reference to Kate?

I think I need to obtain the reference stored in personCache[2] and *change that reference* to a new person.

Thank you

Ryan

Comment: Depending on how often the cache changes and how expensive it is to build, you can either update changed items (as JaredPar shows), or invalidate the whole cache and rebuild it. Rebuilding is useful if one change could have complex effects across many items in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just search for the `Manager` directly and updated it where it points to the old value

```
Person oldPerson = personCache[2];
Person newPerson = new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Kate" };
personCache[2] = newPerson;
foreach (var pair in personCache) { 
  if (pair.Value.Manager == oldPerson) { 
    pair.Vaulue.Manager = newPerson;
  }
}
```

Comment: The relations between objects are fairly complex. I can see that there's opportunity for bugs if I don't remember to 'manually' update all references.

Answer (score 0):

> "... Would have the 'expected' result "

I believe it already has what most people would consider to the the expected result.

One way to achieve what you appear to want is to make the Name property of your Person class writable, then do:

```
personCache[2].Name = "Kate";
```

Another approach would be to store only the Id of the manager in your Person object, rather than a reference to the Manager.  I.e. instead of:

```
personCache[1].Manager = personCache[2];
```

You could have:

```
personCache[1].ManagerId = 2;
```

And you could, for example, have an extension method to get the Manager for a Person:

```
public static Person GetManager(this Person person)
{
    if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
    Person manager;
    personCache.TryGetValue(person.ManagerId, out manager);
    return manager; // returns null if not found in cache
}
```

Comment: I mean 'expected' as in "when i update an object in the cache, that update should propagate to all other objects referencing the original"

Comment: @Ryan, If you update an object in the cache (e.g. change its Name property), the update will "propagate". But what you're describing is "when I *replace* an object in the cache, all other objects referencing the original should be updated to reference the new object".  Which won't happen.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I guess the question should be 'how do I change the reference in personCache[2] from object A to a reference to object B?'